# JAAS and Security - how to use custom tables with GlassFish Security?

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3, jaas

Is it possible to use JAAS with GlassFish but using my custom tables ?

I've got a mapping like this

tbUser -> user_roles <- tbRoles

It's a manytomany with users and roles mapped by an Id into user_roles table, so for this to work with JAAS and GlassFish I would need to change GlassFish custom select to one made by me.

Is it possible to make glassfish use that setup instead of it's default user_table, role_table  without relations ?

I need to use this setup for db, because of the client reqs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post may help: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kumarjayanti/archive/2010/02/01/using-custom-jaas-loginmodules-authentication-glassfish

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use JDBCRealm in GlassFish: 
http://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/jdbcrealm_in_glassfish .